# Can running two cat 5e cables mprove speed between two routers?

Tags: router, switch, cable, cat5e

I have a cable modem downstairs, with 120mbs connection. I have a router upstairs, about 100ft of cat5e cable away. The data rate there is about 50mbs. I added an ethernet switch about halfway, and it improved the speed a bit. Is there a way I can improve the speed further?

Comment: Only by implementing conditional routing ie. Facebook/ Youtube running on a separate cable/port. This will allow other stuff to have a full router port for itself. You are being limited all the time by the internet/ISP facing router bandwidth.

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://superuser.com/questions/212906/does-ethernet-cable-affect-speed.

Comment: I believe you are asking about Link Aggregation (using multiple cables in a coordinated fashion as though they were one cable with 2x bandwidth). If your hardware supports these operations, it is an option. That said however, since you are not even remotely approaching max bandwidth for Cat5E (you are using about 1/20th of gigabit capacity), there is no indication that that would solve any problems for you.

Comment: You might want to look at how you've routed the cable. CAT5 can be very sensitive to sharp bends and pressure on the cable. You might also want to consider how things are earthed. You might be getting some significant interference between the upstairs and downstairs by being on separate earth's. To be honest, to really sort these kinds of issues, you probably need access to a decent cable tester. You might get better results by moving the 2nd router closer and putting the switch upstairs. Also make sure your 2nd router isn't so cheap that it's letting you down.